# submenus height fixing

Tags: joomla, submenu

From the link http://srajib.info/eed/ left side "About Us" all the submenus, sub-submenus height need to be the same. What'll be the css?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean. can you please provide a screenshot or more information as to exactly what you require? thanks

Comment: The link: http://srajib.info/phoca/about-us-submenu-2.jpg

Comment: so you want the text to be vertically aligned with the green bars?

Comment: The link: srajib.info/phoca/about-us-submenu-4.jpg

Comment: out of all honesty, the menu or poorly made. It's using a table so you might be better off downloading a menu from JED.